# Local vs Deployed Laravel Issue

Tags: php, windows, laravel, iis

I am having a weird problem with my Laravel 5.5 app deployed on IIS.

The App has been running for 6 months with no problem, with people adding data into it.

Since yesterday *(No changes on Code Side)* when the people try to save a form the app just hangs, no error what so ever, even if I put debug mode On.

Now for the weird(er) part,  this doesn't happen on all forms  and only happens when using the app "over the internet”, When I Remote into the Server and use the App “locally” then The app works Fine with No Problems.

*I suspect its a php.ini problem but cant be sure*

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, since it works fine locally, I wouldn't think it would be the php.ini. I'd be more inclined to say it's something between your server(s) and the outside world, such as a load balancer or firewall. Open your developer console and watch the network tab when you submit the form to see if there's any hints there, and check the server error logs and laravel logs to see if there are any hints there.

Comment: Thanks. You where right with Firewall problems. I made a hotspot with my phone and It worked.